# Codeigniter view - add item before another one

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter MVC. Let's say I have a json like:

```
[{id:1, parent: null}, {id:2, parent:null}, {id:3, parent:1}]
```

In my view, I go through a foreach this kind of array, and I need to add first the value with id=1, then all the values with parent=1, then the values with id=2 and all the values with parent=2 and so on (in this case, id=3 is skipped since it was already added as parent=1)

For this I have ~300 sql rows and AFAIK I can't make an sql statement that gives me in the order I need (if this is possible, it would solve my problem).

So I need to find another way. I thought about loading the page and on the `$(document).ready` make an ajax call and bring the data, but in this case I have the problem that, since it's a form, in case there is an error I want to reload the page in the same state the user sent it. Since PHP is going to save this state, I can't do it by an ajax call.

Another solution I thought, but I think it's hard on the long term, is to make a mix between PHP and JS like

```
<script><?php (parent != null) ? $("#" + parent).append(content)?></script>
```

But this is giving me some trouble since some content have \n and things I can't control much.

Has anyone had a problem like this or anyone has a way to solve it?

I would like to avoid a solution that makes me go through this array many times

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #json_container span{
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="json_container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonData = [{id:1, parent: null}, {id:2, parent:null}, {id:3, parent:1}, {id:4, parent:2}];
$jsonContainer = $('#json_container');

$(function(){          
    $.each(jsonData, function(i, item) {
        $elm = '<span id="json_el'+item.id+'">'+item.id+'</span>';
        if($('span#json_el'+item.parent).length > 0)
          $($elm).insertAfter('span#json_el'+item.parent);                  
        else
          $jsonContainer.append($elm);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> *Here i added span to separate each element with display as block. It
>   will append if its parent doesn't exist.*

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shafeekb4u/y59032k4/4/)**

Comment: This is one of the options I said. The problem with this is that, since it's a form, it might have some errors, so if that happens, I need to reload the page in the same state as the user left it